# tuple[] for a function input. How to use it?

Tags: solidity, web3js

I'm trying to use this contract https://etherscan.io/address/0x1756438d0038fae9d9566b54a93a4014f4b38953#writeContract.

More specifically, createSplit function. I'm struggling to understand what to plug for an input.

Here's what the contract claims for that part:

```
"inputs": [{
        "components": [{
            "internalType": "address payable",
            "name": "recipient",
            "type": "address"
        }, {
            "internalType": "uint256",
            "name": "percentInBasisPoints",
            "type": "uint256"
        }],
        "internalType": "struct PercentSplit.Share[]",
        "name": "shares",
        "type": "tuple[]"
    }],
    "name": "createSplit",
    "outputs": [{
        "internalType": "contract PercentSplit",
        "name": "splitInstance",
        "type": "address"
    }]
```

Any ideas on what should go for the input? An example would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simple pass them as array of two elements but as a string that should work

```
["0x1756438d0038FAe9d9566b54A93a4014F4b38953","500"]
```

For struct imported within a struct just declare more arrays inside this array.

Answer (score 1):

When you write a `struct` in Solidity, it gets mapped as `tuple` in the ABI. The actual structure of the struct can be seen in the  `components` field (which may be recursive).

In your case, the struct seems to be:

```solidity
struct Share {
    address payable recipient;
    uint245 percentInBasisPoints;
}
```

And the function takes in an array of `Share`

So you should create a JavaScript object which reflects the above structure and pass that to the function.

Comment: I try to use this contract directly on etherscan.

I plug this as an input:
("0x1756438d0038FAe9d9566b54A93a4014F4b38953", 500)

Error: expected array value (arg="shares", coderType="array", value=500)

Comment: Sorry, no idea how struct data should be input in Etherscan

Comment: Try `[["0x1756438d0038FAe9d9566b54A93a4014F4b38953", 500]]`

Comment: @K.Fichter doesn’t work in my case https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/112277 https://i.stack.imgur.com/7s3Cq.png https://etherscan.io/address/0x5A66a1bE5de85e770d2A7AaC6d1d30e39D4f6609#code#F25#L30 https://etherscan.io/address/0x5A66a1bE5de85e770d2A7AaC6d1d30e39D4f6609#readContract

Comment: I am with the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Solidity:

```
struct StructData {
    uint256 x;          
    bytes32 h3;         
}

function registerStructData(
    uint256 _N, 
    StructData[] memory _c
    ) public payable
  returns (uint256) 
  {
      for(uint i = 0; i < _c.length; i++){

        ph = doSomething(_N, _c[i].x, _c[i].h3);
```

and for the typescript code calling this:

```
let overrides = {
          value: ethers.utils.parseEther("1.0"),    // it gets very expensive
          gasLimit: 20000000, 
          gasPrice: 20000000000 
        };

        let structdata: { 
          x: bigint,      
          h3: string,     
         }[] = [];

        for (let idx = 0; idx < CHAIN; idx++) {
          structdata.push({
            x: datasource.x[idx],
            h3: datasource.h3[idx],
          });
        }

        let txConfirm: any = undefined;
        const setChainTx = await contract.registerStructData(
          datasource.N,       // uint256
          structdata,
          overrides
        );
        txConfirm = await setChainTx.wait();
```

I had a hard time figuring out the exact type needed by the values pushed to the array. bigint seemed to work fine, string maps to bytes32 well and you may have to use ethers.BigNumber to cast the value for the price.